# two edit text in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I layout the two edit txt fields in the middle of the screen.
Current layout is not align to middle of the screen (its on the left).

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_code_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_code_2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What layout is Linear layout under?

Comment: inside linear layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your Linear layout width as wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

If its parent layout is Constraint Layout you can Constraint it to left and right side and LinearLayout will remain in middle.

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
and         android:layout_gravity="center"
will do

Answer (score 2):

You have used `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` so it's vertically centered. If you want it to be horizontally centered you can use

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

or if you want both :

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Update with comment :

This solution only works if you replace   `android:layout_width="match_parent"` by `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your LinearLayout

Comment: Your solution only works if he changes LinearLayout   `android:layout_width="match_parent"` by `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, so please update your answer